# Two different announcements from the same iPhone with the same iTunes connection

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

Last time I connected my iPhone to iTunes and I received two different announcements while restoring the iPhone:

**first:**

[image]

> Last archive: Today 21:53

**second:**

[image]

> Last archive:
>   Your iPhone has never been backed up to this computer.

Why it happens like that? The second one is not true...

Answer (score 2):

After restoring your device iTunes will not link it to the previous backup. Your backup whatsoever nonetheless exists. You can find a list of your backups in iTunes Preferences > Devices / If you're using iTunes for Windows, choose Edit > Devices.

By what I understood your first screenshot is before restoring and your second screenshot is after restoring, therefore it makes sense.

Nothing to worry about. Doing a new backup will not delete your old one.

Comment: Agreed on all of this, except that doing a new backup usually does replace/update the old one. Since it looks like you're on a Mac, in that iTunes Preferences > Devices, right click on the old backup and select "Archive" if you want to ensure it stays around.

Comment: Thanks, Kelly! What I said could be misunderstood! iTunes does indeed replace the previous backup of the same phone, it keeps backups of every other phone.